# Does nodetool compact move everything into one SSTable

Tags: cassandra

The Cassandra compaction process reduces the number of SSTables (data files on disk) used to store data. *Minor compactions* occur automatically. You can tell Cassandra to perform a *major compaction* using the `nodetool compact` command.

Does running `nodetool compact` merely perform one round of compaction, reducing the number of SSTables, but perhaps still resulting in there being several SSTables? Or does it always compact all the SSTables (of a column family) into one SSTable?

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on the compaction strategy you set for the table.

For DateTieredCompactionStrategy and LeveledCompactionStrategy, by definition I don't think even a major compaction would combine all the SSTables since that would go against the structure of SSTables they aim to create.

For the default SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, anecdotally it appears a major compaction will combine the SSTables into a single table.  I ran `cassandra-stress -write` and watched the SSTables for a while.  I could see the minor compactions combining SSTables of similar sizes, but not collapsing dissimilar sizes into one.

Then when I'd run a `nodetool compact` on the table, it would combine SSTables of dissimilar sizes into a single table.  I'm not sure if that would be true in all cases.

Taking a quick look at the source, in CompactionManager.java it calls cfStore.getCompactionStrategy().getMaximalTask(gcBefore), which returns a list of tasks that it executes, so that kind of implies it will compact everything, but I didn't drill down any deeper than that.

Comment: If you manually run nodetool compact on a cluster with SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, you're probably going to wait a long long time b4 you get enough SSTables as large as the one you manually created.