# Diagnosing slow Cassandra queries

Tags: cassandra

I'm seeing some slow queries that I don't really understand.

The table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    key text,
    time timestamp,
    id uuid,
    data int,
    PRIMARY KEY (key, time, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time ASC, id ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

The trace looks like:

```
 activity                                                                                                                                                       | timestamp                  | source       | source_elapsed
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------+----------------
                                                                                                                                             Execute CQL3 query | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.821000 | <same ip> |              0
                                              Parsing SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE key = '3-069' AND time <= <30 minutes in the past> LIMIT 1; [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.821000 | <same ip> |             79
                                                                                                                      Preparing statement [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.821000 | <same ip> |            186
                                                                                                  Executing single-partition query on tbl [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.822000 | <same ip> |            661
                                                                                                             Acquiring sstable references [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.822000 | <same ip> |            704
                                                                                                              Merging memtable tombstones [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.822000 | <same ip> |            717
                                                                                                           Key cache hit for sstable 2873 [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.822001 | <same ip> |            750
                                                                                              Seeking to partition beginning in data file [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.822001 | <same ip> |            759
                                                                                                           Key cache hit for sstable 2872 [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.822001 | <same ip> |            887
                                                                                              Seeking to partition beginning in data file [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.822001 | <same ip> |            895
                                                                                                           Key cache hit for sstable 2867 [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.822001 | <same ip> |            992
                                                                                              Seeking to partition beginning in data file [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.822001 | <same ip> |            999
                                                                                                           Key cache hit for sstable 2854 [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.822001 | <same ip> |           1115
                                                                                              Seeking to partition beginning in data file [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.822001 | <same ip> |           1132
                                                                                                           Key cache hit for sstable 2841 [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.822001 | <same ip> |           1243
                                                                                              Seeking to partition beginning in data file [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.822001 | <same ip> |           1252
                                                                                                           Key cache hit for sstable 2828 [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.822001 | <same ip> |           1340
                                                                                              Seeking to partition beginning in data file [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.822001 | <same ip> |           1348
                                                                                                           Key cache hit for sstable 2771 [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.822002 | <same ip> |           1463
                                                                                              Seeking to partition beginning in data file [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.822002 | <same ip> |           1470
                                                                                                           Key cache hit for sstable 2562 [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.822002 | <same ip> |           1577
                                                                                              Seeking to partition beginning in data file [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.822002 | <same ip> |           1585
                                                                Skipped 0/8 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.823000 | <same ip> |           1705
                                                                                               Merging data from memtables and 8 sstables [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.823000 | <same ip> |           1715
                                                                                                        Read 2 live and 0 tombstone cells [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:55.652000 | <same ip> |         831025
                                                                                                                                               Request complete | 2016-09-28 16:33:55.717105 | <same ip> |         896105
```

There are only 11 cells for this primary key, and this query returned one cell. Can anyone explain why a read of a small number of cells without any tombstones is so slow? Are there some other metrics I should be looking at? CPU and disk utilization look fine on the machine, and GC times are fairly steady and low.

Comment: What version of Cassandra are you using?

Comment: @JeffBeck 2.2.5

Comment: So you have the old storage model so there is a single row for your partition key and you are having to read them all off the sstables since you are scanning a number of columns so you have to join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have the partition splitted in 8 different SSTables:

```
Merging data from memtables and 8 sstables [SharedPool-Worker-5] | 2016-09-28 16:33:51.823000 | <same ip> |           1715
```

If you are on slow spinning disks (eg 7200 RPM), this directly translates to multiple disk seeks: your query is being limited by the amount of IOPS that your disk subsystem can deliver.

To mitigate this problem you could try to merge all the SSTables into a bigger one. This would indeed cause one seek only. Depending on your compaction strategy settings (check [the documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/compactSubprop.html#compactionSubpropertiesSTCS) for fine tuning STCS), you could issue a major compaction with `nodetool compact`. Check this SO question: [Does nodetool compact move everything into one SSTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32506997/does-nodetool-compact-move-everything-into-one-sstable)

If you don't want to run a compaction (could take long time, or could not work completely), you could try to move the CF to an SSD with a symlink (stop the node, copy data, symlink the directory, start node). Having SSDs more IOPSs than spinning disks, you should see the effect immediately.

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

The other metrics you want to be watching is for a table you want to know how many SSTables per read you are using. If you have too many that will slow things down which is what the other answers are getting to.

You can get that data via nodetool [tablehistograms](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/tools/toolsTablehisto.html).

```
nodetool tablehistograms keyspace tbl
```

That will give you a breakdown of how many sstables are being hit for different requests. You can also see this data in opscenter if you are using that. Look for `TBL: SSTables per Read (percentiles)`

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your scenario with the following script (using CCM)

```
ccm create cas-1 --vnodes -n 1 -v 2.1.15
ccm start
echo "create keyspace test WITH REPLICATION={ 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1} ;" | ccm node1 cqlsh
echo "create table test.tbl (key text,time timestamp,id uuid,data int,PRIMARY KEY (key, time, id));" | ccm node1 cqlsh
echo "insert into test.tbl (key,time,id,data) values ('1','2000-1-1',now(),1);" | ccm node1 cqlsh
ccm node1 nodetool flush
echo "insert into test.tbl (key,time,id,data) values ('1','2000-2-1',now(),1);" | ccm node1 cqlsh
ccm node1 nodetool flush 
echo "insert into test.tbl (key,time,id,data) values ('1','2000-3-1',now(),1);" | ccm node1 cqlsh
ccm node1 nodetool flush 

echo "tracing on;  select * from test.tbl where key='1' and time <= '2000-3-1' limit 1;" | ccm node1 cqlsh
echo "tracing on;  select * from test.tbl where key='1' and time <= '2000-3-1' limit 1;" | ccm node1 cqlsh
```

which produces a similar trace.

```
Now Tracing is enabled

 key | time                     | id                                   | data
-----+--------------------------+--------------------------------------+------
   1 | 1999-12-31 22:00:00+0000 | ac0791c0-85b9-11e6-9005-51c5fe8b2280 |    1

(1 rows)

Tracing session: ae3ebd10-85b9-11e6-9005-51c5fe8b2280

 activity                                                                                           | timestamp                  | source    | source_elapsed
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------+----------------
                                                                                 Execute CQL3 query | 2016-09-28 23:25:22.018000 | 127.0.0.1 |              0
 Parsing select * from test.tbl where key='1' and time <= '2000-3-1' limit 1; [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2016-09-28 23:25:22.019000 | 127.0.0.1 |            570
                                                          Preparing statement [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2016-09-28 23:25:22.020000 | 127.0.0.1 |           1055
                                      Executing single-partition query on tbl [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-09-28 23:25:22.022000 | 127.0.0.1 |           4065
                                                 Acquiring sstable references [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-09-28 23:25:22.023000 | 127.0.0.1 |           4091
                                                  Merging memtable tombstones [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-09-28 23:25:22.024000 | 127.0.0.1 |           4132
                           Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 3 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-09-28 23:25:22.024000 | 127.0.0.1 |           4388
                                  Seeking to partition beginning in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-09-28 23:25:22.024000 | 127.0.0.1 |           4398
                           Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 2 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-09-28 23:25:22.025000 | 127.0.0.1 |           4761
                                  Seeking to partition beginning in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-09-28 23:25:22.025000 | 127.0.0.1 |           4770
                           Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 1 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-09-28 23:25:22.025000 | 127.0.0.1 |           4991
                                  Seeking to partition beginning in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-09-28 23:25:22.025000 | 127.0.0.1 |           5000
    Skipped 0/3 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-09-28 23:25:22.026000 | 127.0.0.1 |           5148
                                   Merging data from memtables and 3 sstables [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-09-28 23:25:22.026000 | 127.0.0.1 |           5159
                                            Read 2 live and 0 tombstone cells [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-09-28 23:25:22.027000 | 127.0.0.1 |           5365
                                                                                   Request complete | 2016-09-28 23:25:22.023661 | 127.0.0.1 |           5661
```

The key (partition key) you are querying (in my sample '1') in your case '3' has data in multiple sstable files (in the above I have forced this by flushing sstables after every insert).

Since the query is filtering by clustering key and using "limit 1" all the sstables that hold data for the partition key need to be searched. Once all rows are retrieved they are ordered and the first result is returned.

If you will remove the "limit 1" you should get multiple results back

in my sample

```
echo "select * from test.tbl where key='1' and time <= '2000-3-1';" | ccm node1 cqlsh
Now Tracing is enabled

 key | time                     | id                                   | data
-----+--------------------------+--------------------------------------+------
   1 | 1999-12-31 22:00:00+0000 | ac0791c0-85b9-11e6-9005-51c5fe8b2280 |    1
   1 | 2000-01-31 22:00:00+0000 | acd60550-85b9-11e6-9005-51c5fe8b2280 |    1
   1 | 2000-02-29 22:00:00+0000 | ad8a3a20-85b9-11e6-9005-51c5fe8b2280 |    1

(3 rows)
```